# AngularJS Mock - expect vs when

Tags: angularjs, mocking

What is the difference between `expect` and `when` in the `ngMock` AngularJS module?

They both provide a response, so when would you use one over the other?

I read the docs at angularJS.com, but it was not very clear to me.

This is the service I want to test using Jasmine, so should I expect a endpoint was called, or should I bank on a known value being returned?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('cs');

    app.service('PlateCheckService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            checkPlate: function (plateNumber) {
                return $http.post('PlateCheck/Index', {
                    plateNumber: plateNumber
                }).then(function (response) {
                    return {
                        message: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'Clean' : 'Hot',
                        alertClass: response.data.VehicleAtl === null ? 'alert-success' : 'alert-danger'
                    };
                });
            }
        };
    }]);

}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation in the doc is crystal clear to me:

> Request Expectations vs Backend Definitions
>
> Request expectations provide a way to make assertions about requests made by the application and to define responses for those requests. The test will fail if the expected requests are not made or they are made in the wrong order.
>
> Backend definitions allow you to define a fake backend for your application which doesn't assert if a particular request was made or not, it just returns a trained response if a request is made. The test will pass whether or not the request gets made during testing.

So, if you use `when()`, you can do any request, in any order, and the test won't fail. If you use `expect()`, then the test will fail if the backend doesn't receive the expected requests, in the same order as the expected ones.